# TeX Gyre Pagella not working in pdflatex after update

Tags: pdftex, miktex

I've been using Pagella to typeset a 400-page book using MiKTeX with no issues until the May Pagella update. Now when I run pdflatex, I get the error:

> !pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file qplb.pfb.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font file f
>   or reading
>    ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Any suggestions would be very welcome - I've tried reinstalling MiKTeX several times with no improvement. I can generate a DVI file with no errors.

Comment: It is a bug in the map files. I reported it already.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad it's not something foolish I did!

Comment: I have the same problem, lucky i found this post before i started doing some things i dont quite understand.

Comment: The problem should be fixed with the update from this morning. In a few tests I just run the TeX Gyre fonts worked just fine.